# About HighStock multiple data tooltip

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

i want show multiple data in tooltip
but highstock's example is only one data in tooltip

i tried find ask and example, but I could only find examples for highchart

==============================================================

my code > (tooltip's abc and toto is show undefined )

```
  series: [{
                name: '',
                data: [{       
                    x:1452870000000,
                    y: 56.33,
                    abc: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                    toto:'op'
                }, {        
                    x:1453870000000,
                    y: 24.03,
                    abc: 'Chrome',
                    toto:'uo'
                }, {      
                    x:1455870000000,
                    y: 10.38,
                    abc: 'Firefox', 
                    toto:'fq'
                }
                       ],                
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    radius: 3
                },
                shadow: true     
            }],

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<span>'+this.point.abc+this.point.toto+'</span>';
                }                    
            }
```

Comment: so,How to set the data other than the xydata and I would like to know how to display the data in a tooltip.
please tip to me T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option shared:true in the tooltip section to show data of all series at the same time on the tooltip:

```
 tooltip: {
            shared:true
        },
```

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/mauq02kL/)

```
$(function () {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];

    /**
     * Create the chart when all data is loaded
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function createChart() {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },

            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent',
                    showInNavigator: true
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2,
                //split: true,
                shared:true
            },

            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }

    $.each(names, function (i, name) {

        $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can get more information about how to use the tooltip option [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip).

Comment: Thanks for your tips,

Comment: Your suggestions are very helpful.

Comment: is that what you wanted?